# Flutter Implementing pause and play..... Streaming Music

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried multiple flutter plug-ins to stream and play and pause music but as of currently, I haven't yet figured out a simple way to implement play and pause, whilst having the ability to avoid music overlapping, I want so that when the current song is playing, if I were to press play on new music track, the current song playing will stop and play the newly pressed song. I've tried flutter_sound, audio player, audio file player, and flute music player but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

If it is possible either using one of these or a new plug-in, is there a way to implement what I have just described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you seek is more of a multi-track player than a player. Which does not currently exists AFAIK.

The simplest way is to act according to the status of the tracks (which should be given by the player).

Roughly, what I suggest: have something that keeps the status (e.g. paused, playing, completed) of each track. (e.g. List of Tracks) When you press play on track 2 or track 1 finishes playing, you set to 'completed' (or as you wish) the track 1 and set to 'playing' the track 2.

Have a listener on the status of the current track and voila (for autoplay). When the track completes, notify the listener to call a function to start the next one on your list. When you press another track, set to 'completed' the current track and to 'playing' the track you pressed, then notify listeners.

Any library letting you know the status of a track is good enough for your purpose.